# What is the difference between Get-WmiObject and Get-Counter in Powershell

Tags: performance, powershell, windows-server-2008

I'm trying to learn how to do some simple Windows Server performance monitoring. From what I've read it looks like there are two ways to get this information in Powershell: `Get-WmiObjects` and `Get-Counter`.

What is the difference between `Get-WmiObjects` and `Get-Counter`? Is there a reason I would want to use one over the other? Could it be that the two methods are reading from the same data-source but are formatting their results in different ways?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no difference between them. Performance counters are all registered in WMI, so the Get-Counter cmdlet would implicitly be using WMI to grab its data.

In general, I would recommend using Get-WmiObject since it's a broader interface, and becoming familiar with that broader interface would be valuable to you.

Keep in mind that not all cmdlets in PowerShell are necessarily necessary to learn and understand. There are tons of commands that I simply do not use whatsoever, because I have no need for their functionality. Set-WmiInstance is a perfect example -- why use that, when I can use Get-WmiObject to grab an object, change it, and call Put() on it? Then again, I prefer to treat things as .NET objects instead of using cmdlets (generally).

Comment: Thank you Trevor. I assume with the broader interface you are talking about things like WQL? Also, the Get-Counter also has a nice partner command called Export-Counter which can then be loaded as a graph into Perfmon. Is there anything like that with the straight WMI query?

Comment: Mark, what I meant is basically that you can get a lot more information using Get-WmiObject instead of Get-Counter — it's a more generic interface. As for your second question, the Export-Counter uses input of the [PerformanceCounterSampleSet] type, which is a custom object created by the Get-Counter cmdlet. You might be able to construct this same object type using your own function, in conjunction with Get-WmiObject, but I surmise that just using Get-Counter would be easier.

Comment: The Get-Counter measurements are in the root\cimv2 WMI namespace with the naming convention of Win32_PerfFormattedData_*